# $2$-groups Tag Confusion

Tags: discussion, tagging, tag-management, tag-wikis

Currently our [$2$-groups](https://math.stackexchange.com/edit-tag-wiki/4280) tag concern about [$p$-groups](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/P-group) with $p=2.$ However there is another well established notion of [$2$-groups](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2-group) in algebraic topology/homotopy theory about $2$-dimensional higher groups. In fact, it generalizes to [$n$-group](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/n-group) for any $n\in\mathbb{Z}.$ This is a very unfortunate coincidence of terminologies. But usually it does not confuses people in day-to-day mathematics as they belongs to two quit far away fields.

As far as I know, currently we don't have questions about the second notion of $2$-groups and therefore it does not make sense to construct one immediately (but we may need to do so one day). What I am interested in is, how can we create a new tag for this second notion without destroying the existing tag and without making a confusion?

Comment: Something to keep in mind if the need arises.

Comment: Maybe you could ask and answer a question in the second category, just so a tag can be created for it

Comment: @BenjaminWang: I am curious about the process of making a such tag while there is another tag with the same name for on a different thing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think `2-groups-higher-categories` and `n-groups-higher-categories` would clearly signal what they were talking about. I'm not sure anyone is asking questions about these, though.

Answer (score 11):

It is not possible to have two tags with the same name. There are a few options to work around such things.

For example we have [divisors-algebraic-geometry](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/divisors-algebraic-geometry) to signal what type of divisors we mean.

One can also group things together to disambiguate, for example "divisors-and-multiples" would convey what divisors are meant as well.

For the current case, frankly,  I don't see a need for the 2-groups tag, p-groups should suffice.

Comment: While $2$-groups are technically a special case of $p$-groups, their properties are very different from other $p$-groups of odd order, and are generally considered to be a different topic by group theorists. They are treated with different books, for example.

Comment: Fair enough, I still don't think that tag is overly useful. I mean it seems to get one or  two questions a year or so.

Comment: yes, conceptually it is distinct, but it doesn't seem to be very active. I wouldn't be opposed to repurposing it for algebraic topology if that topic has more interest.

Comment: If we need the other I'd go for "higher order groups" or some such thing.

Comment: I'd support that.